# NIC Throughput samp

Tags: java, network-programming, nic

I am writing in java and I need to periodicly get the output of my NIC(the same information that I see in windows task manager),is there a way to sample the current throughput of the NIC in java?

Comment: When you say "sample the throughput", do you mean checking to see how many frames or bytes/sec are being sent/received from the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has no built-in way to access low-level OS information like NIC utilization. You can write a JNI library that accesses the information using the C/C++ API for your specific OS.

Comment: can you give an example for such code(C/C++) for windows. At least can you give example for such API(c/c++) for winodws?

Comment: No, I don't use Windows. You might ask a new question about that specifically (with `Windows`, `networking` tags).